# Removing applications from Show Applications without uninstalling

Tags: uninstall, gnome-shell, .desktop

I do some Android development on my Ubuntu installation, because of it I need JavaJDK installed.

That's all fine, except for some reason the JavaJDK has now something like 15 different icons in my "Show Applications" list that I cannot remove.

[image]

I, of course, don't want to uninstall any of them in fear Java might stop working completely, so just a way to remove them from "Show Applications" would be good enough for me.

How would I do that? I know these are `.desktop` files somewhere on my system, but I can't seem to find them.

This has been plaguing me for a while, my Show Application window is just full of garbage I can't remove

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Application launchers shown in *Activities* or *Applications* overview are usually located either in `/usr/share/applications/` (system-wide applications) or `~/.local/share/applications/` (for current user) as `.desktop` files.

You can hide an individual launcher from Activities or Applications overview by adding an extra

```
NoDisplay=true
```

line to the corresponding `.desktop` file or by deleting the `.desktop` file altogether.

It is generally not advisable to edit the `.desktop` file located in `/usr/share/applications/`. Instead copy the file to `~/.local/share/applications/` first and make the necessary changes to the copied file.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it's not advisable to edit in `/usr/share/applications/` and won't copying it create duplicates? I managed to get the icons down to 6 after adding `NoDisplay` to all of them, but I'm not sure what to do with those last ones that are still there. Any way to see what file is responsible for each icon?

Comment: I found the filename, it's `invisible-openjdk-8-policytool.desktop` but it's not in either folder.

Comment: @creativiii It's because `/usr/share/applications/` is a system directory, any changes you make to files there may be be overwritten by an update to a related package. So you may have to edit the file again and again. The directory `~/.local/share/applications/` has higher priority . Copying should not crate duplicates, but should locally override the associated `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications/`.

Comment: Not sure what I did but after copying the Java `.desktop` files from `/usr/share/applictions` into `~/.local/share/applications/`those last 6 icons disappeared. Thank you!

Comment: @pomsky Your answer is technically correct. But why you do not want to use `alacarte` GUI?

Comment: @N0rbert In my personal experience Alacarte does not work. I tried multiple times to fix this problem with it to no avail.